# Best practice for passing a single line of input to a command's stdin using bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a command-line program which takes input from stdin. What's the best way for me to pass a line of stdin into that program using bash? I have two approaches which accomplish the job, but they both seem a bit clunky.

I'll illustrate my approaches using a dumbed-down example of counting three words.

using a here doc:

```
wc -w <<EOS
one two three
EOS
```

using echo:

```
echo 'one two three' | wc -w
```

As I said, both of these seem a bit clunky. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
wc -w <<<"one two three"
```

is a shorter way.

Comment: I sometimes prefer writing this the other way around, to make it obvious the input flows to the command, e.g `<<< "one two three" wc -w`

Comment: @Phil, whatever pleases your aesthetics ;-) I personally prefer first command and then whatever arguments it accepts whether via input or as a command line parameters. Exception is environment variables, but when I have a choice (e.g. make, configure scripts) I put those at the end too.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen the `echo` one used most often.

A third option, which might be Bash-only (I haven't checked) is the "here-string", `<<<`

```
wc -w <<<"Hello people of StackOverflow"
```

(you can find out more about those in the `Here Strings` section of the Bash manual)

Comment: I'd say, according to question tag, bashism is okay.